# Form with Button to Remove Brackets and Text Inside Brackets

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how to set up this function to target text in the input form 'STOCK1'.

Javascript as it stands:

```
function removeBrackets(element) {
document.body.innerHTML = element.replace(/\[[^\]]+\]/g, '__');
}
```

HTML as it stands:

```
<button onclick="javascript:removeBrackets(element)">Remove Brackets and Text Inside Brackets</button>

<input type="text" name="STOCK1" id="STOCK1" placeholder="Place text here..." />
```

Please help me to understand how this should work! Many thanks!

Comment: Not what you're asking about, but you do *not* need the `javascript:` prefix inside event handler attributes. I'm voting to close this as "too broad", because what you really seem to need is a general tutorial on how to use JS to manipulate DOM elements. Your regex for the actual replacement looks OK (assuming you don't want to replace empty brackets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `document.getElementById('STOCK1')` to `removeBrackets` call, set `.value` of `element`  instead of setting `document.body.innerHTML`. Note, you can alternatively use `RegExp` `/\[.*\]/g`.

```html
<script>
function removeBrackets(element) {
 element.value = element.value.replace(/\[.*\]/g, '__');
}
</script>
<button onclick="removeBrackets(document.getElementById('STOCK1'))">Remove Brackets and Text Inside Brackets</button>

<input type="text" name="STOCK1" id="STOCK1" placeholder="Place text here..." />
```